# LARAVEL Project not displaying on Github

Tags: php, laravel

So, I tried pushing my laravel project to github but surprisingly, none of my directories where displaying only my readme file was displaying, below is an image of the repository on github

[Laravel Repo on Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytuh0.png)

I tried commenting my gitignore files but I discovered it was taking about an hour to push to github so I killed the process, below are my gitignore files

```
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
.env
.env.backup
.phpunit.result.cache
docker-compose.override.yml
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
/.idea
/.vscode
```

Have googled but I could not find a solution for it, will appreciate any help I can receive.

[My files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIVw8.png)

Comment: Did you make sure, to commit AND push it. Plus.. is the correct branch selected / checked out?

Comment: I did, it was even the first time I will push the project to the repo on github so it was my first commit

Comment: Alright, so ill guess you also pushed. Did you check, if there are any other '.gitignore' files or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows `main` branch, which has `1 commit`.

But if nothing is there, add them.

Run these:

```
git add .
git commit -m "All files"
git push origin main -f
```

Comment: I tried something like this before and roughly about 30 minutes after its stil sending all my files to Github

Comment: @pheloumi OMG! so you stop it before finishing?! No wonder you don't see your files; The way `Git` works is that only once `push` command returns successfully, **then and only then** you will see files on Github.
Either you have **bad internet connection, or you are adding too large files**. Not much can be done about your internet, but ensure you add only files required to Git (BTW, I removed `-f` option from `add` command; try again.)

Comment: I was able to commit it but am now having this issue fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Emmanuel5012/basiclesson.git/': OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to github.com:443  while trying to push. I guess its an internet connection related problem. If there are ways around it please let me know.

Comment: @pheloumi recently Github stopped supporting `HTTPS`, and now `SSH` is the only way to `push` (see: https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.0/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)

Comment: I have an SSH key set but its not requesting for my SSH key while trying to push to github. NB: Am pushing from mylocal files.

Comment: @pheloumi Git never asks for your SSH key; you need to configure local manually (at least once); Open your `.git/config` file (and edit remote).

Answer (score -1):

put the following characters your the gitignore file then try push your project on the github

.gitignore

```
# Created by https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/laravel
# Edit at https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore?templates=laravel

### Laravel ###
/vendor/
node_modules/
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log

# Laravel 4 specific
bootstrap/compiled.php
app/storage/

# Laravel 5 & Lumen specific
public/storage
public/hot

# Laravel 5 & Lumen specific with changed public path
public_html/storage
public_html/hot

storage/*.key
.env
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json
/.vagrant
.phpunit.result.cache

# End of https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/laravel
```